# Using MenuBlockService with my custom menu

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use the MenuBlockService that Sonata Project's Block Bundle provides with one of my menus that I have built with KNPMenu. I do not see any documentation on how to use the MenuBlock with a custom menu. This is what my KNPMenu looks like.

```
<?php

namespace XYZ\AdminBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MenuBuilder
{
  private $factory;

  /**
  * @param FactoryInterface $factory
  */
  public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory)
  {
    $this->factory = $factory;
  }

  public function createMainMenu(Request $request)
  {
    $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');

    $menu->addChild('Home', array('route' => 'admin_xyz_user_user_list'));

    return $menu;
  }
}
```